# Não foi possivel localizar o driver (PDOException “could not find driver”)

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

Estou tentando fazer uma conexão com o meu banco de dados FIREBIRD, porém quando eu organizo certinho, coloco o IP de onde ele se localiza etc. Aparece a mensagem:

> NAO FOI POSSIVEL LOCALIZAR O DRIVER EM c/wamp/www////

O que devo fazer pessoal ?

```
 $user = "SYSDBA";
$pass = "masterkey";

$pdo=new PDO("firebird:localhost=IP AQUI;dbname=Duosig_producao",$user,$pass);
```

Comment: O driver está habilitado no phpinfo()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver no entando a linha correta para habilitar o PDO do firebird no php.ini é

```
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```

E não

```
extension=php_firebird.dll
```

Comment: @gmsantos Na versão antes de editado parecia que ele estava comentando sobre a resposta do MysticPower

Answer (score 3):

Verifique se você esta com drive ativado você pode fazer assim:

```
foreach(PDO::getAvailableDrivers() as $driver) {
  echo $driver;
}
```

Se não houver o drive habilite no seu `php.ini` as seguintes extensões:

```
extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_firebird.dll
```

Reinicie o apache e verifique se o drive esta ativo.

Outra coisa, você precisa especificar o caminho do seu Banco de dados exemplo:

```
$str_conn = "firebird:dbname=C:\db\banco.gdb;host=localhost";

$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, "SYSDBA", "masterkey");
```

links: [PDO FIREBIRD](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php) , [FIREBIRD CONNECTION](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.connection.php)